# Is recording possible using java applets?

Tags: java

I am trying to build a web app that will be able to run in browser and perform recording and caching locally on the client's computer. After searching my different options for the last few weeks I came up with the possibility of using java applets. As much as you know, is it possible to record audio using Java applets? How strict are the security issues in this environment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible, but only from a "signed" applet.  It is strict in that regard because an applet could otherwise be spying on a user without their knowledge.  Therefore the applet has to be signed, meaning that the user has to deliberately allow it to run. The "signed" part gives information about the publisher of the applet.

[Java Signed Applet Tutorial](http://java.sun.com/developer/onlineTraining/Programming/JDCBook/signed.html)